How to Bring a Desktop Application to the Foreground from a Web Application via a Tray App
I have a web application that needs to trigger actions in a desktop application (not under my control). This desktop application provides an integration API, but only for other desktop applications, not web apps. To bridge this gap, I created a third desktop application (a .NET C# tray app) which listens on a specific port for HTTP requests from the web application and then forwards commands and changes focus to the desktop application.
The issue I'm facing is that since the tray app runs in the background, it cannot change the focus from the browser (web application) to the desktop application.
I have tried several methods found online, including:

AllowSetForegroundWindow(-1)
SetForegroundWindow
SwitchToThisWindow
Running the executable as an administrator

Despite these efforts, none of these methods bring the desktop application to the front. Instead, the desktop app's icon just flashes orange in the taskbar.
Changing the ForegroundLockTimeout registry key to 0 works as expected, but I would like to avoid this approach.
When running the program under Visual Studio, it behaves as expected. However, running the executable outside Visual Studio only results in the icon flashing orange, and the functions return false with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.
Could someone help me resolve this issue? Is there a workaround to make this work as it is? Or can you advise me on another approach to achieve the desired behavior?
